# Cant get symbolic link to work (windows 7) cmd

Tags: windows, syntax, cmd

Am trying to create a symbolic hard link so that I can move chrome's cache to another harddrive,  I have been trying to get it to work, but every variation I have tried has come back from the command line that my syntax is incorrect. From what ive seen seaching about this error is normaly todo with the quotation marks.

Anyway this is what I have so does anything have any idea why its returning "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Thanks

```
mklink /J “C:\Users\Vodkaholic\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data” “K:\Chrome\User Data”
```

Comment: Are you really using curly quotes (“/”)?  That's likely a problem.  Try using straight quotes (").

Comment: Thanks its been a long day :)

Comment: Note that a "symbolic hard link" is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use straight quotes (`"`) instead of smart quotes.

Comment: when copying and pasting, it looks like it is the same quote, but it is not